# How to avoid + signs getting replaced with spaces in GET parameters (Django)?

Tags: python, django, string, url, get

I've found myself in need of passing email addresses in GET parameters, but I noticed + signs get replaced by spaces, so that an URL like `example.com?param=myemail+alias@example.com` will, when captured through something like `request.GET.get("param", None)`, yield `myemail alias@example.com`.

For now I opted for the arguably crude and risky way of `replace()`ing spaces with + signs but I'd like to know: is there a better way to pass email addresses in GET parameters (that will work with Django 3+)?

Comment: since `+` is the URL encoding for blank, you need to URL encode `+` (`%2B`)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to url encode them.

```
import urllib.parse
urllib.parse.quote_plus({'email': 'myemail+alias@example.com'})
```